# Parsing google calendar XML feed

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got XML feed from public google calendar. Looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <feed xmlns='................' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
        <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/........./public/full</id>
        <updated>2009-08-24T10:57:00.000Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'/>
            <title type='text'>Sports Events</title>
    .....
        <entry>
            <id>...........</id>
            <published>2009-08-14T00:29:58.000Z</published>
            <updated>2009-08-14T00:29:58.000Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'/>
..............
            <georss:where>
                <gml:Point>
                    <gml:pos>11.111111 -22.22222</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </georss:where>
            <gd:eventStatus value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed'/>
            <gd:transparency value='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.transparent'/>
            <gCal:uid value='.........@google.com'/>
            <gCal:sequence value='0'/>
            <gd:when startTime='2009-10-03' endTime='2009-10-04'/>

.............
```

Now to PHP:

```
$calendar = simplexml_load_file('http://my.feed.com');
foreach ($calendar->entry as $item) {
    //here I get the whole <entry> node
    $gd = $item->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    // now in $gd I have all nodes like <gd:XXXXX>
}
```

The problem is how to get value from here?

```
<gml:pos>11.111111 -22.22222</gml:pos>
```

Its not present in my $gd variable, how to get this node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I highly recommend using this library: https://github.com/collegeman/coreylib. It'll make everything from start to finish mind-numbingly easy.

Comment: Oh this is just brilliant. Thank you for showing me this library :)

Comment: Haha my pleasure! it's great, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry this is old, but could you explain how you exactly got it to work? I had similar code and the same exactly problem as you but I'm not exactly sure how to use coreylib. Thank you!

Comment: Yesterday lost entire day with Google Calendar API. Concluded it was too complicated as I only needed to gather data, nothing else. With this I did it within 1min... brilliant!!

Answer (score 5):

There are of course several ways to parse the XML. [Display Google Calendar events on your PHP Web site with XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-xpath/) (see "Parsing the Google Calendar feed with PHP") and [Integrate your PHP application with Google Calendar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/) are two comprehensive resources with sample code and more.

Personally, I used the following approach:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->load('http://my.feed.com');
$entries = $doc->getElementsByTagName("entry"); 
foreach ( $entries as $entry ) { 
  $titles = $entry->getElementsByTagName("title"); 
  $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $times = $entry->getElementsByTagName("when"); 
  $startTime = $times->item(0)->getAttributeNode("startTime")->value;
  $when = date("l jS \o\f F Y - h:i A", strtotime($startTime));
  // ...
}
```

In order to access the georss namespace etc. have a look at (and its output)

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('*', '*') as $element) {
  echo 'localName: ', $element->localName, ', prefix: ', $element->prefix, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Zend GData library to parse Google web services (including the calendar). It's easier than trying to use the XML code manually. There is a tutorial that shows you how to do this [here](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/55762.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Full Calendar was MUCH easier than Coreylib. Coreylib wasn't drop dead simple, although I'm sure it is very powerful.

I had FullCalendar running in 5 minutes. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: This question is tagged php, so your jQuery solution is out of line and misleading if you’re not even stating it’s a jQuery alternative.