# Why is <gd:when> missing from this google calendar xml feed?

Tags: php, xml, perl, google-calendar-api

Why doesn't this [XML representation](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/n978gdn7eioep3gk22t0r5b450%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic) of a public Google calendar contain any <gd:when> tag like I can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347033/parsing-google-calendar-xml-feed)?

The associated [ical representation](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/n978gdn7eioep3gk22t0r5b450%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics) seems to contain start and end dates for the events.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: I need to end the url with 'full', not 'basic'.

Explained here: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html

Answer (score -3):

Because it doesn't have to?
Because it doesn't?
Because of some google bug?
Because of some google feature?...

*Am I missing something?*

Why google something or other is the way it is, doesn't exactly seem like a question for stackoverflow :)

Comment: Well, I hoped that someone with experience parsing Google calendar's XML may be able to tell me how to get the events' date and time out of it.